# Подключение к Postgres с помощью Prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, pgadmin, prisma

Ошибка в подключение к базе данных с помощью Prisma. Подключение через PgAdmin прошло без проблем. Многое перепробовал, менял версию prisma, менял версию Node  16.13 на 16.18, все безуспешно.

`` P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432` ``

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    String  @id @db.Uuid
  phone String? @unique @db.VarChar(15)
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: school_postgres
    image: postgis/postgis:12-3.1-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/postgres/create-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-database.sh
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: ${POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD}
      DATABASE_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE: ${DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE}
      TEST_DATABASE: ${TEST_DATABASE}

  pgadmin:
    container_name: school_pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.8
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '8080:80'

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

**.ENV File**

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
DATABASE_USER=db-admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=db-admin
DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE=school_development
TEST_DATABASE=school_test

PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=school@it.ru
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=school-it

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@localhost:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?connect_timeout=300"
```

**Package.json**

```
"@prisma/client": "^3.5.0"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251937/error-p1001-cant-reach-database-server-at-localhost5200

Comment: В данной теме нет ответа на вопрос. У меня бд находится в контейнере, а приложение я запускаю локально, так что конфиги правильные.

Comment: а вы попробовали заменить в адресе слово локалхост на наименование контейнера?

Comment: Ради эксперимента да, но имя контейнера указывается только если приложение находится с базой в одной сети. А так как postgres поднимается в контейнере, то подключение  происходит через localhost.

Comment: UPD: Нашел проблему и решение.
Проблема была в том что на компьютере был установлен и запущен локально Postgres на порту 5432, и в контейнере я поднимал Postgres на 5432, не знаю почему не было конфликтов, но после замены порта в контейнере все заработало.